# Specific htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove all numeric fragments of the url on the third position, if the first fragment matches a single string `xxxx`.

Example:

```
example.com/xxxx/hello/1
```

should become

```
example.com/xxxx/hello
```

and

```
example.com/xxxx/hello/1/anything
```

should become

```
example.com/xxxx/hello
```

but

```
example.com/xxxx/hello
example.com/abcd/hello/anything
example.com/xxxx/hello#12
```

should be kept unchanged.

Comment: Readers generally appreciate an initial attempt from question authors. Would you use the documentation to research this, and to make an attempt? If you cannot get it to work, edit it into this question, and readers will have a clearer idea of where you are going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt what you ask is actually what you want... Why? Because that would mean that you lose important information most likely. Information typically important and required for your application to actually work. An example: if `https://example.com/xxxx/hello` is, as you claim, what you want as URL, then what internal resource should get requested in the end? `/xxxx/hello/1 ` or `example.com/xxxx/hello/1/anything`? Are you really certain that you want to deliver the same content in both cases? If so, then why two different URLs initially?

Comment: Yes @arkaschka, I'm certain. It's supposed to handle redirects from legacy urls to the new url.